# Is this broken gas valve off?

Tags: plumbing, natural-gas

We just bought a home and were moving the dryer. The gas valve at the appliance seems to have a broken handle.

Is this in the off position? I was trying to put it perpendicular to the pipe.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It's not broken. Some valves are (were) made with only a flat rectangle or square knob. This style design cannot be rotated without the help of a tool. Somebody (maybe you) has inserted a bolt through the hole in the knob probably to make it possible to turn by hand.

You're correct: it is rotated to the off position.

Comment: It's off provided that it's not broken :-)